# Transports supported in iPad for SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr, real-time

in iPad with Safari browser what kind of transports are supported for SignalR. What is the fallback mechanism in iPad Safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Transports and fallbacks section of this page](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr), SignalR first tries to use WebSockets and Server Send Events.  Then it'll fall back to Frame or Long Polling as a last option.

Safari on an iPad supports WebSockets.  But it should be noted that iOS Safari implements a different standard: HyBi-00/Hixie-76 (not RFC 6455).  Server send events work too, but only if the page is active on screen.

I am not sure if older versions of Safari on iPad (iOS 5/6) will fall back to other transports - but you could use http://websocketstest.com to test that.

Answer (score 2):

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/websockets) iOS Safari supports websockets. However, there seems to be some [reported issues](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2650) with it, so it might be best to force it to use long polling or something else.

The best way to check the behavior would be to enable Safari debugging on the iOS device, and connect to it with a Mac to monitor the network traffic in the browser.